# Data from Garmin devices (edge 510) via bluetooth

Tags: android, ios, cordova, bluetooth, garmin

I am newbie to Garmin devices and required to develop a cycling app (Android and iOS) which should able to get the data from Garmin devices (eg. Edge 510) via bluetooth. I have successfully connected the Garmin device to the app and unable to get anything.

Is there any way i can use Garmin device in my app via bluetooth?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you connected in your app? Can you show any code?  The manual refers to pairing the device which implies that it is Bluetooth 2.1 not Bluetooth 4.0/Low Energy, so you won't be able to use Core Bluetooth to connect to it in iOS.

Comment: Using serial bluetooth plugin (Cordova) and Garmin Connect app. In my app it shows the device info. but doesn't give any data even the device (edge 510) status is "connected" with the phone.. bit confusing!!

Comment: Is that on Android or iOS?

Comment: Tested on Android so far...

Comment: The serial bluetooth plugin won't work on iOS.  I can't help with Android, sorry.

Comment: NP mate. will look around. Thanks ;)

Comment: user5091906 , could you find an answer for this question?I'm working on a project that a Android tablet should be connected to a garmin gps.i'm interested in this matter too

Comment: R1349, I'm using Garmin Connect API (paid) which lets users to connect their Garmin account to my app and this is how i get their rides. There is no way i can connect my app to the Garmin devices to get the data. Hope this saves your time. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No,
But you could use ANT to read the data from the sensors.
https://www.thisisant.com/developer/resources/downloads/#software_tab

Answer (score 0):

The Garmin IQ iOS SDK allows you to connect to your Garmin device with bluetooth. SDK with Sample App is here https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/sdk/

Comment: But did you make a tests for it? How in reality MailBox class works? How to communicate usinq IQ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the changelog in the readme file in the SDK for version 2.2.2.

Remove support for communicating with the mobile Connect IQ SDK in the API for Edge, Oregon, and Rino devices.

It was removed :(